# Is there any callback or event from which I can get user details when user uninstall my Microsoft teams app?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

> My teams app contains a bot feature and I have created my bot in nodeJs. I'd like to know if there is any event which is triggered whenever user uninstalls my app.

Answer (score 1):

The `conversationUpdate` event with the membersRemoved object in the payload is sent when either your bot is removed from a team, or a user is removed from a team where a bot has been added. Microsoft Teams also adds `eventType.teamMemberRemoved` in the channelData object. As with the membersAdded object, you should parse the membersRemoved object for your bot's App ID to determine who was removed.Please take a look at [Handle Bot Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-removed)

Comment: Would this apply in a 1-1 situation as well? I've never tested that myself, but just curious

Comment: Your bot receives a conversationUpdate with membersAdded when a user adds it directly for personal chat. In this case, the payload that your bot receives doesn't contain the channelData.team object.

Comment: yeah, sure, for when a user -installs- the bot, I'm curious whether I'd receive a membersRemoved conversationUpdate if the app is uninstalled?

Comment: I am facing this issue, I don't receive membersRemoved event in case of uninstall when bot is installed in a personal scope only.